# Smarty + gettext: Changes in the PO file are not shown in the web pages

Tags: php, smarty, gettext, po

Using PHP + Smarty + Gettext, I am trying to localize my webpages.

Everything was ok, but suddenly the changes in my PO file are not taken into account by the webpages.

This is what I do:

1) I modify the contents of the PO file:

```
msgid "Hello World"
msgstr "Hallo mal wieder Welt!"
```

2) I convert the PO file intothe MO file with 'msgfmt' (via shell) or with Poedit.

3) I refresh the webpage, and "Hallo Welt!" (the previous translation) is shown, not the current "Hallo mal wieder Welt!"

4) I try by deleting, creating again, and 777-chmoding the 'templates_c' directory (the location of the compiled templates of Smarty), but with no success

What happened? Thank you very much.